# Are constant terms in second-quantization relevant?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, greens-functions, second-quantization

I have a rather broad question and a specific problem. Let's take a orthonormal single-particle basis $\{ \vert i \rangle \}$, a simple single-particle Hamiltonian 
$$\tilde{H} = \sum_{i, j} h_{i j} \vert i \rangle \langle j \vert$$
and its second-quantized form
$$ H = \sum_{i, j} h_{ij} a^\dagger_i a_j ~.$$
Now I add a constant $C$, i.e. $H_C = \sum_{i, j} h_{ij} a^\dagger_i a_j + C ~.$
The broad question is, if this constant is relevant. Does it have any effect? How does one deal with a constant operator in Fock space? What is the single-particle version of $\tilde{H}_C$? I was unable to find literature about this. Such constants sometimes appear when one wants to define a Hamiltonian with a particular symmetry, e.g. particle-hole symmetry, and as far as I can tell, these constants are ignored or considered unimportant.

The specific problem, why I want to know about the consequences of these constants, is the following. (Don't worry about the details, just concentrate on the Hamiltonian.) The single-particle imaginary-time Green's function is defined as
$$ G_{k l}(\tau) = - \frac{1}{Z} \mathrm{Tr}(e^{-\beta H} \mathcal{T} a_k[\tau] a^\dagger_k) ~,$$
with $Z = \mathrm{Tr}\left( e^{-\beta H} \right)$, $\beta = 1/T$ and $a_k[\tau] = e^{\tau H} a_k e^{-\tau H}$. It's Fourier transformation is defined as
$$ G_{k l}(i \omega) = \int_0^\beta d\tau e^{i \omega \tau} G_{k l}(\tau) ~.$$
They fulfill the relations
$$\begin{align}
\partial_\tau G_{k l}(\tau) &= -\delta(\tau) \delta_{k l} - \sum_{m} h_{k m} G_{m l}(\tau) \\
\delta_{k l} &= \sum_{m} (i\omega \cdot \delta_{k m} - h_{k m}) G_{m l}(i\omega) ~. \tag{1} \end{align}$$
We see that $G(i\omega)$ -- understood as a matrix -- is inverse to $Q$ with $Q_{k l} := (i\omega \cdot \delta_{k l} - h_{k l})$. Another approach is given by the resolvent $\mathcal{G}(z) = (z - \tilde{H})^{-1}$. Then $\mathcal{G}_{k l}(i \omega) = \langle k \vert (i \omega - \tilde{H})^{-1} \vert l \rangle$ which apparently satisfies Eq. [(1)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133009/are-constant-terms-in-second-quantization-relevant#mjx-eq-1) and therefore $\mathcal{G}_{k l}(i \omega) = G_{k l}(i\omega)$. This is a useful relation and used at several occasions in the previous research from students and my research.

Now what happens if we use $H_C$ instead of $H$ in the definitions of $G(\tau)$ and $\mathcal{G}$? Naively I would expect the constant to drop out from $G(\tau)$ as it appears in the enumerator and denominator and can be factored out. But I can't see something similar happen for $\mathcal{G}$. Does the equality not hold anymore?

Comment: The identity operator $\mathrm{Id}$ of the Fock space acts like the identity on any subspace with fixed particles (this is very easy to prove), so $C=C\mathrm{Id}$ acts on the one particle subspace as the multiplication by $C$. As in QM, the constant is not so relevant since it does not change the dynamics, however it is sometimes useful: e.g. in the [Nelson model](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/5/9/10.1063/1.1704225), where subtracting a constant (that in the limit becomes infinite) is necessary to renormalize the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @yuggib Ok, yea, I guessed that it acts likes this but was not sure. Thank you. That means in this case that the constant induces an energy shift of the $h_{i i}$, and it probably does not simply cancel out of the imaginary-time Green's function. So the equality still holds. That's better than nothing, but I still need an argument why it was and is ignored in the hitherto research. They did not mention it. In my Hamiltonian there is an interaction $\propto (a^\dagger_i a_j - 1)(a^\dagger_k a_l -1)$ and we just ignore the resulting +1 even though it is an operator... hm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant $C$ is not a part of the single-particle Hamiltonian. It is what is called the vacuum energy, and has no observable effect unless we look at gravitation.

To be specific, adding this constant to the Hamiltonian makes $e^{-\beta H}\,\rightarrow e^{-\beta C}e^{-\beta H}$ and $Z=\rm{Tr}(e^{-\beta H})\, \rightarrow\, e^{-\beta C} Z$. That is, the same factor $e^{-\beta C}$ is introduced to both the numerator and denominator in the expression for the imaginary-time Green's function, and they cancel out.

**Update:** OP considered a Hamiltonian of the form $H = \sum_{ij} h_{ij} |i\rangle\langle j|$, which translates into $H = \sum_{ij} h_{ij} a_{i}^{\dagger} a_{j}$ in the second quantization. If we call this a single-particle term in the Hamiltonian, it is inescapable that an $n$-particle term should be what consists of $n$ creation and $n$ annihilation operators in its second quantized form.

According to this definition, an $n$-particle term acts on the subspace of the Fock space corresponding to (# of particles)$\ge n$. In this regard, an overall constant in the second-quantized Hamiltonian is a zero-particle term, or the vacuum energy.

As a concrete example, let's consider the following second quantized Hamiltonian:

\begin{equation}
H = C + \sum_{ij} h_{ij} a_{i}^{\dagger} a_{j} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ijkl} V_{ijkl} a_{i}^{\dagger} a_{j}^{\dagger}a_{l} a_{k}.
\end{equation}
Then, its first-quantized form when there are $N$ particles should be
\begin{equation}
H = C + \sum_{p=1}^{N}\sum_{ij} h_{ij} |i\rangle_{p}\langle j|_{p} + \sum_{p=1}^{N}\sum_{q=p+1}^{N} \sum_{ijkl}V_{ijkl} |i,j\rangle_{p,q}\langle k,l|_{p,q},
\end{equation}
where $|i\rangle_{p}$ is a state in the single-particle Hilbert space of the $p$th particle, whereas $|i,j\rangle_{p,q}$ is a state in the two-particle Hilbert space of the $p$th and $q$th particles ($p<q$).

Comment: To be acting only on the vacuum $\Omega$, it has to be of the form $C \lvert\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega\rvert$. Usually, when you write a number as an operator, you intend it multiplied by the identity operator, so it acts on any vector as the multiplication by $C$, the single particles ones as well.

Comment: @yuggib Vacuum energy is present regardless of the number of particles in the system. Hence it is indeed an operator that is proportional to the identity acting on the Fock space.

Comment: then it is also part of the single particle Hamiltonian, because it acts also on that subspace.

Comment: @yuggib I guess we should clarify what we mean by a single-particle Hamiltonian. To me it means a term of the form $H_{1} = \sum_{ij} h_{ij} a_{i}^{\dagger}a_{j}$. Similarly, a two-particle Hamiltonian would be of the form $H_{2} = \tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j,k,l} h_{ijkl} a_{i}^{\dagger}a_{j}^{\dagger}a_{l}a_{k}$. On the other hand, the vacuum energy is just a constant.

Comment: For me, as well as the OP, is the restriction of the Hamiltonian to the single particle subspace. However it is just a matter of terminology.

Comment: @yuggib OP suggested that the single particle Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \sum_{ij} h_{ij} |i\rangle\langle j|$ in the first-quantized form translates into $H = \sum_{ij} h_{ij} a_{i}^{\dagger}a_{j}$ in the second-quantized version. Notice that according to this rule, the identity operator in the first quantization, i.e.,  $\sum_{i} |i\rangle\langle i|$, becomes the total number operator $\sum_{i} a_{i}^{\dagger} a_{i}$ in the second quantization. Considering this, the vacuum energy should not appear in the single-particle Hamiltonian, as it is the identity operator in the whole Fock space.

Comment: Let $\mathscr{H}_1$ be the one-particle subspace. $H\bigr\rvert_{\mathscr{H}_1}=\hat{H}$; while $(H+C)\bigr\rvert_{\mathscr{H}_1}=\hat{H} +C$. It is evident that $C$ influences the one-particle subspace, even if it is not written as a second quantized operator. The procedure of second quantization is a convenient mathematical tool, but the physically relevant operator is $H$.

Comment: @yuggib I have no disagreement with your mathematics. The point is that the vacuum energy operator acts identically on zero-, one-, two-, ... particle subspaces. The single-particle Hamiltonian consists of e.g., the kinetic energy. If we have $N$ particles, we have $N$ kinetic energies. On the other hand, the vacuum energy is always a fixed constant $C$ regardless of the number of particles. If you insist on your definition of the term "single-particle Hamiltonian" I won't argue it because it is ultimately a matter of preference, although I find it somewhat awkward.

Comment: the important thing is that we agree on the math, the rest is terminology as you say ;-).

Comment: I discussed the topic with students from CM and PP and I think it boils down to a definition problem: A constant term in in the Hamiltonian was not considered in the formalism - and its derivation - that I use. Hence it is not clear how $\tilde{H}_C$ is defined. Furthermore, in my formulae appears a sum over all interactions and usually only a finite number of interactions is nonzero. The system is infinitely big and if I shift all interactions by $+C$ - depending on the definition - then the sum diverges. So I think, they just ignored $C$ or, in other words, measured energies relative to $C$.

Comment: @hauntergeist  Shifting all interactions by $C$ is certainly unphysical. If your second-quatized Hamiltonian is given by $\sum_{ij} h_{ij} a_{i}^{\dagger}a_{j} + C$, this $C$ should not show up in its first-quantized form $\sum_{ij} h_{ij} |i\rangle\langle j|$.

Comment: @hauntergeist I updated my answer. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: @higgsss I suppose that $\vert i \rangle_p \langle j \vert_p = 1 \otimes \ldots \otimes 1 \vert i \rangle_p \langle j \vert_p \otimes 1 \ldots \otimes 1$ and $\vert i, j \rangle_{p, q}$ is (anti)symmetrized. Yea, your first-quantized form of the fixed-number Hamiltonian makes sense. Then $C$ can not simply be regarded as a single-particle term $\vert i \rangle_p \langle j \vert_p$, and I think that's what previous researchers meant with $\tilde{H}$ in $\mathcal{G}$. Maybe you could supply a reference where the relationship between first and second quantization is explained in detail.

Comment: And the interaction shift I mentioned earlier is bullocks.

Comment: @hauntergeist Sure. $|i\rangle_{p}\langle j|_{p}$ should be accompanied by identities acting on Hilbert spaces of other particles. One doesn't need to (anti)symmetrize multi-particle states in the first-quantization, though. It is OK as long as the Hamiltonian is invariant under exchanging labels of particles. Second quantization arises when we restrict our attention to subspaces consisting of states that are bosonic(fermionic) under exchange of labels of particles, and appropriately define creation/annihilation operators connecting subspaces corresponding to different particle numbers.

Comment: @hauntergeist Not really sure about the best reference discussing the connection between 1st and 2nd quantizations. I personally found Fetter & Walecka and Negele & Orland useful.